# Loading Object arrays in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data stored in a file xyz.json

```
[
{"_index":"company","_type":"items","_id":"10","_score":0,"_source":{"id":"10716","name":"Car","city":"tokyo","status":0}},
{"_index":"company","_type":"items","_id":"10","_score":0,"_source":{"id":"10716","name":"Bus","city":"tokyo","status":0}},
]
```

I want to import this into Elastic Search, how do I do that?

Comment: localhost:9200/company/items Should list all the items.

Comment: just loop and save it in the structure said by @Karma

Comment: @RohitKumar I got frustrated and did that in the end. There should have been a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below from [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) document which help in importing bulk documents and I hope this will help you

```
$ cat requests
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }

$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests; echo
{"took":7,"items":[{"create":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"1","_version":1}}]}
```